# Avoiding "set session transaction read" in spring boot application with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

Thanks for looking at this. I have a tomcat spring boot application using JPA/Hibernate with mysql database back end. There are REST controllers exposed and various service methods are annotated with `"@Transactional"`.

There are entity and repo objects used by JPA/Hibernate to persist and query data from the mysql database. The SQL queries are generated by JPA Hibernate entity and repo objects, like as follows:

```
public interface FooRepo extends JpaRepository < Foo, String > {
}
```

The above means that there is a table Foo which has a primary key of type String. There is also a separate class Foo.

While using the above FooRepo to query a single row in the table I see the following SQL queries

```
set session transaction read 
select * from Foo where id='IdToQuery';
set session transaction read write
```

I understand the select SQL statement but not able to understand why "set session transaction read" is being executed?

Thanks,
ash

Comment: Are you using `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` ?

Comment: Only using `@Transactional` in the annotation for the service methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Googling, the only suggestion that I found was to implement a separate read-only transaction connection pool. 
From: http://256stuff.com/gray/docs/misc/performance_optimizing_spring_hibernate_transactions/